# ABRIR o SELECT quando o "hover" ou "focus"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Já procurei em diversos sites, porem não achei um que fosse o que queria, os que vi expandem o select usando o size e não é isso que quero, quero como se fosse um clique do usuário sobre o select, ele não empurra nada pra baixo, nem ocupa mais espaço, apenas aparece sobre as demais opções, sobrepondo o que tem por baixo.

Aqui, um dos meus testes, porem não é desta forma que quero.

```js
$("#contPrazo").hover(function(){
  $("#contPrazo").attr("size","4");
});
$("#contPrazo").focus(function(){
  $("#contPrazo").attr("size","4");
});

$("#contPrazo").mouseleave(function(){
  $("#contPrazo").attr("size","1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="contPrazo" name="contPrazo">
 <option value="30">30 MESES</option>
 <option value="12">12 MESES</option>
 <option value="24">24 MESES</option>
 <option value="36">36 MESES</option>
 <option value="48">48 MESES</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei aqui, não é possível abri-lo não. Talvez você possa criar um [objeto dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) para fazer isso, ao invés de um select.

Comment: Vc pode criar um componente, usando UL/LI mas que tenha a aparencia igual a de um Select, ai sim com CSS ou JS fica mais fácil de manipula-lo. Se é que essa possa ser uma opção para vc... O bootstrap mesmo não tem um select, o select dele é construído com outros elementos HTML

Comment: uso bootstrap, mas desconheço esse "select" deles, em meus forms sempre uso `<select class="form-control" id="" name="">`

Answer (score -1):

Segundo este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432610/jquery-open-select-by-button) do SO e este [outro link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048213/open-select-using-javascript-jquery/11642008), e além de outos que consultei para responder a sua pergunta, depois de eu mesmo ter tentado,suponho que NÂO há como mostrar as `options` de um `SELECT`, com o passar do mouse.

Em contra partida, acredito que o suposto `SELECT` que você mencionou em sua pergunta correponde a um `dropbox`, que provavelmente associado a alguma função JS preenche algum `input:hidden` com o valor correspondente a `li` clicada.

Comment: sim seria um dropdown, proem quero fazer isso pra um formulario, entao um dropdown que apenas envia pra outra pagina, ou coisa do tipo nao me serve, seria um select mesmo, que eu seleciono e aquilo ao enviar o form vem no GET/POST

Comment: Você pode adicionar um evento no dropdown que preenche algum campo oculto do formulário, fazendo com que seu dado seja enviado.